# Print Pane or Whole FXML Page JAVAFX

Tags: javafx, printing, fxml

How to Print Pane OR whole FXML Page. 
I try these two method (doPrint and doPrintSecond is in Controller)to Print but not working;
please correct me where i am wrong.
is there any other way to print the fxml page or pane .

FXML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="186.0" prefWidth="457.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication10.PrintPaneController">
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="printPane" prefHeight="139.0" prefWidth="457.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="179.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Print">
               <font>
                  <Font size="45.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="152.0" layoutY="93.0" text="JavaFX print Pane">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <Pane layoutY="139.0" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="457.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
         <children>
            <JFXButton buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="192.0" layoutY="14.0" onAction="#printActionPane" text="Print">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller Code

```
package javafxapplication10;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class PrintPaneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Pane printPane;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField name;    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void printActionPane(ActionEvent event) {
        //First Method
        doPrintSecond(root);

        //Second Method
        if (doPrint(printPane)) {
            System.out.println("Print");
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }

    //First
      void doPrintSecond(Node printPane) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if (job != null) {
            boolean printed = job.printPage(printPane);
            if (printed) {
                job.endJob();
            } else {
                System.out.print("Faled");

            }
        } else {
            System.out.print("could");

        }
    }
      //Second 
        boolean doPrint(Node printPane) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if (job == null) {
            System.out.println("1");
            return false;
        }
        if (!job.showPrintDialog(null)) {
            System.out.println("2");
            return false;
        }
        if (!job.printPage(printPane)) {
            System.out.println("3");
            return false;
        }
        return job.endJob();

    }
}
```

[This is Application and i click in print button but it not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTmpA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to print Pane. Also with the help of **PageLayout** you can set the **size of paper** you want, its **orientation** and also you can set the **margin** for your page.

I hope this helps!

```
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, 
    PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(printPane.getScene().getWindow())) {
      boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, printPane);
      if (success) {
        job.endJob();
      }
    }
```